# Finding specific attribute in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, attributes

I'm trying to get the Date, **"Di 10.Dez 2019"** out of the following HTML

```
soup = `<div aria-disabled="false" aria-label="Di 10. Dez. 2019" aria-selected="false" class="DayPicker-Day" role="gridcell" tabindex="-1">\n <div class="DayPicker-Day-Inner">\n  <span class="DayPicker-Day-Date">\n   10\n  </span>\n  <span class="DayPicker-Day-Price">\n   56\n  </span>\n  <span class="DayPicker-Day-Currency">\n   CHF\n  </span>\n </div>\n</div>\n`
```

So far I tried different approaches, like this one:

```
soup.find(lambda tag: tag.name == 'aria-disabled="false".aria-label=' in tag.get_text())
```

This just returns a non value.

I can't figure it out. Can anyone of you help? Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to get the date using JavaScript?

Comment: I try to get it via python beautifulsoup

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
txt =  """<div aria-disabled="false" aria-label="Di 10. Dez. 2019" 
aria-selected="false" class="DayPicker-Day" role="gridcell" tabindex="-1">\n 
<div class="DayPicker-Day-Inner">\n  <span class="DayPicker-Day-Date">\n   10\n  
</span>\n  <span class="DayPicker-Day-Price">\n   56\n  </span>\n  
<span class="DayPicker-Day-Currency">\n   CHF\n  </span>\n 
</div>\n</div>\n"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
soup = bs(txt, "lxml")

dat = soup.select_one("div[aria-label]")
dat.attrs['aria-label']
```

output:

> 'Di 10. Dez. 2019'